# How to use array again after removing some elements on it

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have a sample array of:

```
let sampleArray = ["spider", "regards", "sorry"];
```

If I use **if statement** and remove some elements on it, how can I declare the new sample array with new value.

This is my code:

```
let sampleArray = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];
     //let say the value of "fruits = apple"       
    if(sampleArray.includes(fruits)){ // will return TRUE, since 'apple' is included in the sampleArray

    //Now, I will remove it on the array
    sampleArray = sampleArray.filter(e => e !== fruits); 
    console.log("sampleArray: ", sampleArray) // return ["banana", "orange", "grapes"]
```

Now, how can I apply it in the **SAME** if statement again `if(sampleArray.includes(fruits))`  so that if I call it again the value is now  `["banana", "orange", "grapes"]` and my new fruits is grapes to have new array of `["banana", "orange"]`

Is this possible? I can only use the statement `(sampleArray.includes(fruits))` once.

Comment: What do you mean by *"once"*? Turn it into a function, with `fruits` and the array as the arguments.

Comment: i am not clear Do you mean u want to keep unchanged ur `sampleArray ` ?

Comment: why not use splice and indexOf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove any value from your array using **filter() method** for reuse the new array you have to store that in a new variable

[filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) does not change the original array

```js
let sampleArray = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];
var fruits = 'apple';
if(sampleArray.includes(fruits)){
let newArray = sampleArray.filter(e => e !== fruits);   //let say the value of "fruits = apple"   Now, I will remove it on the array 
console.log("afterRemove: ", newArray) 
console.log("sampleArray: ", sampleArray) // will return TRUE, since 'apple' is included in the sampleArray 
}
```

Other way to make this happen

```js
let sampleArray = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];

function checkforemove(v) {
  return v !="apple";
} 

   
 var newarray = sampleArray.filter(checkforemove);
console.log(newarray);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function which accepts fruits as a parameter and then change values accordingly.

```js
let sampleArray = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];

let func = (fruits) => {
  if (sampleArray.includes(fruits)) {
    sampleArray = sampleArray.filter(e => e !== fruits);
    console.log("sampleArray: ", sampleArray)
  }
}

func('apple')
func('orange')
```

**Note:-** Personally i don't like function with side effects as it becomes very hard to debug them. so i generally avoid mutation as much as i can. if i had to this i will do it this way

```js
let sampleArray = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];

let func = (array, fruits) => {
  if (array.includes(fruits)) {
    return array.filter(e => e !== fruits);
  }
  return array
}

let sampleWithoutApple = func(sampleArray, 'apple')
console.log(sampleWithoutApple)

let sampleWithoutAppleOrange = func(sampleWithoutApple,'orange')
console.log(sampleWithoutAppleOrange)
```

Answer (score 1):

use below simple code,
created a function named with fruits which accept parameter.

```js
var sampleArray = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];

function fruits(fruitname){//this function will filter name which we pass if name not there then it will return all the collection(array)
    return sampleArray.filter(e => e !== fruitname)
}

fruits("banana")//please send item name here except that remaining will return.
fruits("apple")
//console.log(fruits("banana"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function for this.

Try this:

```js
let sampleArray = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];
function doesIncludes(fruits){
  if(sampleArray.includes(fruits)){
    sampleArray = sampleArray.filter(e => e !== fruits);
    console.log("sampleArray: ", sampleArray) //
  }
}

doesIncludes("grapes")
doesIncludes("orange")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and call it using new values of fruits

```js
let sampleArray = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];

function x(fruits) {
  if (sampleArray.includes(fruits))
    sampleArray = sampleArray.filter(e => e !== fruits);
  console.log("sampleArray: ", sampleArray)
}
let fruits = 'apple'
x(fruits)
fruits = 'grapes'
x(fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use splice and indexOf?

```js
let sampleArray = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];

function remove(arr, item){
  let toRemove = arr.indexOf(item);
  if (toRemove != -1){
    arr.splice(toRemove, 1);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(remove(sampleArray, "apple"));
console.log(sampleArray);

console.log(remove(sampleArray, "orange"));
console.log(sampleArray);

console.log(remove(sampleArray, "apple"));
console.log(sampleArray);
```

then you can use it like:

```js
let sampleArray = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];

function remove(arr, item){
  let toRemove = arr.indexOf(item);
  if (toRemove != -1){
    arr.splice(toRemove, 1);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function eat(sampleArray, fruit){
  if (remove(sampleArray, fruit)){
      // fruit exists and already removed, do something
      console.log(fruit, 'eaten, now you have', sampleArray)
  } else {
      // fruit not exists, do another thing
      console.log('nothing to eat, you still have', sampleArray)
  }
}

eat(sampleArray, 'apple');
eat(sampleArray, 'orange');
eat(sampleArray, 'apple');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure to close over your `sampleArray` (ie: `fruits`) which you can then call on individual fruit items to remove from your fruits array:

```js
const f = fruits => fruit => {
  if (fruits.includes(fruit))
    fruits = fruits.filter(e => e !== fruit);
  return fruits;
}

const removeFruit = f(["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"]);
console.log(removeFruit('apple'));
console.log(removeFruit('grapes'));
```